# Uploading Audio File with datetime and String as name

Tags: java, android

I am uploading an audio file to a server, which works perfectly when the file name is something like:

abcd.3gp.

The problem is that anytime I record and upload another file, since the name is constant it overwrites the existing file which is not what I want. I want to always have a new file. I also do not want to use random numbers or anything like that.

So what I am doing now is that I have a datetime format in which I have removed all - or / and : from it and I store it in a variable.

For example, if I have this date:

2014-06-23 10:16:23

I turn this into:

06232014_101623

and then I add some extra text to it to get something like this:

06232014_101623ABC.3gp

This is the format that I want it in.

The problem is that when I record, it works and saves it perfectly with this name but when it starts to upload, I get a File Not Found exception, even though the file exists and is there.

The moment I change the name to something like abcd.3gp I get no exception and it uploads.

This is the code for recording:

```
Date currentDateTimeString= new Date();
DateFormat sdf;
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy_hhmmss");
String  strDate = sdf.format(currentDateTimeString);
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mFileName += "/"+ strDate+TNumber+".3gp";
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}

mRecorder.start();
```

This is the code for uploading:

```
    Date currentDateTimeString= new Date();
    DateFormat sdf;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy_hhmmss");
    String  strDate = sdf.format(currentDateTimeString);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;       
    String existingFileName = 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            existingFileName+= "/"+ strDate+TNumber+".3gp";

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    String urlString = "http://10.15.15.149/androidphp/Uploadaudio.php";

    try {

        //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = 
        new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName));
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // close streams
        Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }

    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {

        inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String str;

        while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {

            Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);

        }

        inStream.close();

    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any clue or assistance would be appreciated very much.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. 
The problem was with the variable declaration scope for the currentDateTimeString. So After recording the audio file, since it is a date and time , the time changes before it starts uploading. So it in that case it will always have a different datetime value attached to the rest of the string which is different from the one on saved.
So I change the scope of the variable and now it holds the same datetime value through out